# Remove carriage return and special characters from text

Tags: java, replace, special-characters, replaceall

I am writing a code in java that takes text then remove all the Punctuations (, blanks - new line and numerals) all special character and just leave the A to Z letters. it works fine until gets to the first carriage return and stopped. 
 I tried many version of replaceAll but it did not work, please help!

for example

> IHN EMATMG EECNIWEA RSHI A RESOEF ES RLTCMEE-COEAACIROH TLNHR PIRMOA
>   ECSHENEV CEDIAODED ULS NPHD TN EAE REIIY-MO TWL-EDTHTTEEN NTCIPRO TO
>   TUERYMT MORCCIECLL,
>
> PIMAATODMC DNL IITIAMRO CUNAIMYNAOINI.

then I get:

> IHNEMATMGEECNIWEARSHIARESOEFESRLTCMEECOEAACIROHTLNHRPIRMOAECSHENEVCEDIAODEDULSNPHDTNEAEREIIYMOTWLEDTHTTEENNTCIPROTOTUERYMTMORCCIECLL

```
 package Cipher1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StripCipher
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Take the input of the encrypted text from the user.
        System.out.println(" Enter the cipher text : ");
        Scanner ScanText = new Scanner(System.in);
        String OriginalCipherText = ScanText.nextLine();

        // Eliminate the wide space and special characters present in the input
        // text.
        String CipherText = OriginalCipherText.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        CipherText = OriginalCipherText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
        System.out.println(" Striped Cipher text is : " + CipherText);

        // Calculate the length of the text.
        int CipherTextLength = CipherText.length();
        System.out.println(" Lenght of the cipher text is : " + CipherTextLength);
    }
}
```

for clarifications I used the following but none of them work:

```
replaceAll("[\n\r]", ""); 
replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "")
replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]",""); 
replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]","");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceAll` returns a String with the replacements. The original string stays the same. Now, the problem is that you're having two `replaceAll` calls from the same original String and the second simply overwrites the changes from the first one:

```
String CipherText = OriginalCipherText.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
CipherText = OriginalCipherText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

You probably want

```
String CipherText = OriginalCipherText.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
CipherText = CipherText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

or a combined Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be ScanText.nextLine() as it will read line until new line is detected so in your case it will stop taking string after MORCCIECLL, I have tried to supply hard coded string and its work fine

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextLine()` scans up to the next line separator.  What you will probably have to do is continue reading lines and join them together.

Comment: How would you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**one** Never ever start a variable name with a capital letter! Capital letters are for types ("FooBar") and for constants ("FOO_BAR"), a variable should be called like "fooBar":

```
static final FooBar FOO_BAR = new FooBar();
FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
```

**two** I agree with Artjom B. String is an immutable class. Every method that at first *might* look like it is changing the original string actually returns a new string containing the changed data. This way you can even easily chain the method calls using fluent notation:

```
String cipherText = originalCipherText.replaceAll("\\s+", "")
                                      .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

But then [^a-zA-Z] also contains \s, so your solution can be reduced to a one liner:

```
String cipherText = originalCipherText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

**three** I also agree with J Earls, Jekin Kalriya on the Scanner being the root of your problems. If you want to read multiple lines, you need to iterate the Scanner's lines:

```
while (true) {
  final String cypherText = scanText.nextLine()
                                    .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
  System.out.println(cypherText);
}
```

Mind that in your scenario:

1. this get's you into an infinite loop as the System.in never ends! You would to check for a certain input like to stop the iteration.
2. The output comes after each line typed to the console.

Comment: Thank you guys for clarification but when I tried the three part. it read every paragraph alone is there are a way to read the whole text.

Comment: Since your reading from System.in‒how would you get *in* several paragraphs at once?